# Workaround for Jackson infinite recursion in third party classes

Tags: java, json, jackson, cyclic-reference

Is there any way of programatically telling jackson to ignore a property? For instance, by name.

My problem is that I'm serializing third party objects, some of which have parent/child cyclic dependencies that cause

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Infinite recursion (StackOverflowError)
```

Because I can't modify the code, [the usual ways of breaking cyclic dependencies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3325387/infinite-recursion-with-jackson-json-and-hibernate-jpa-issue) don't work for me.

I'm using an `ObjectMapper` and `ObjectWriter`:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.setSerializationInclusion(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL);
mapper.setVisibility(new VisibilityChecker.Std(JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.ANY));
writer = mapper.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter();
writer.writeValueAsString(object);
```

And I know they're highly customizable, as with the serialization inclusion and visibility that I have in the snippet, but I can't find they way of achieving something like

```
mapper.ignoreProperty("parent");
```

Comment: What version of Jackson are you using?

Comment: @DarthAndroid: 2.6.3

Answer (score 5):

You should use Jackson's [Mix-In Annotations](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonMixInAnnotations) to break the cyclic dependency:

```
objectMapper.getSerializationConfig().addMixInAnnotations(ClassWithParent.class, SuppressParentMixIn.class);
```

And then define `SuppressParentMixIn`:

```
public interface SuppressParentMixIn {

    @JsonIgnore
    public ParentClass getParent();

}
```

This allows you to programmatically insert annotations on classes that you don't control. Whenever Jackson goes to serialize `ClassWithParent`, it will behave as if all the annotations from `SuppressParentMixIn` were applied to `ClassWithParent`.

Comment: Thanks, that is very likely what I'm looking for. However, it doesn't work. I've gone twenty times over the names of the properties, but there still has to be something that I'm missing.